# How to do group_concat in select query in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to do GROUP_CONCAT in select query in sequelize here is my requirement what i want

```
SELECT `group_name`, `description`, GROUP_CONCAT(`module_name`) FROM `group_access` GROUP BY `group_name`
```

I want to write this type of query in sequelize.

This is what i tried.

```
groupAccess.findAll({
    attributes: ['group_name', 'description', 'GROUP_CONCAT(module_name)'],
    group: ['group_name']
})
```

But it is showing error `Unknown column 'GROUP_CONCAT(module_name)' in 'field list'`

How to write GROUP_CONCAT in sequelize. I even searched in there website but not found any solution. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to *Sequelize* documentation, you need to use `sequelize.fn` to do aggregation:
Something like this (not tested):

```
groupAccess.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'group_name',
    'description',
    [sequelize.fn('GROUP_CONCAT', sequelize.col('module_name')), 'module_name']
  ],
  group: ['group_name']
})
```

*Sequelize* [Querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html).